# Convert value of object into PHP variable (smarty)

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to the the value of a HTML tag to a PHP variable. The code I have below will not work, the value of {mytag} is 21.

I have  {mytag} as an HTML hook inside the smarty template to extract a field from a db, so I have to have {mytag}.

The plan is to use the int from the db inside some maths but as {mytag} is treated as an object I have to get the value into another variable.

```
$t = new stdClass;
$t->bat = "{mytag}";
$bar = $t->foo;
ob_start();
$b = var_export($bar, true);
echo $b;
$stdClass = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$the_var = $stdClass;
```

When I check the output I get the name but not the value.

```
echo $the_var[0] 
//prints ' and not 2
echo $the_var[1] 
//prints { and not 1
```

How can I get $the_var to contain value 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a small solution but should work.

```
{php}
$the_var = "$this->get_template_vars('mytag')";
{/php}
```

From [smarty docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl):

> get_template_vars() — returns assigned variable value(s)
>   array get_template_vars(string varname);